# getApplicationContext in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i am trying to get the `Context` of my MainActivity in my Fragment class but don't know what am missing  this is what i tried so far -

i hav a customAdapter class -

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<String> result;
String [] resultArray;
Context context;
ArrayList<String>  imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String>  prgmNameList, ArrayList<String>  prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView noteTitle;
    TextView noteId;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_list, null);
    holder.noteTitle=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
    holder.noteId=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewOID);

    final int index = result.indexOf(position);
    int index2 = imageId.indexOf(position);

   // holder.noteTitle.setText(result[index]);
    holder.noteTitle.setText(result.get(index));
    holder.noteId.setText(imageId.get(index2));
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result.get(index), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}

}
```

and have a Fragment class which extends Fragment -

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);


    List_View = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.notesList);


    context =  getActivity().getApplicationContext();



    List_View.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter( here am having Problem  ,notesArray , notesIDArray));
```

as you can see according to my CustomAdapter class i have to put Context as parameter but don't know how to get the context of my MainAcivity

`List_View.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter( here am having Problem  ,notesArray , notesIDArray));`

i already tried `getActivity` and `getActivity().getApplicationContext();` but i don't think think this is what it wants any guideline for getting mainActivity's 
Context in my Fragment class would be so helpful for me

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to actually require `MainActivity` so change:

```
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String>  prgmNameList, ArrayList<String>  prgmImages)
```

To:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context mainActivity, ArrayList<String>  prgmNameList, ArrayList<String>  prgmImages)
```

And pass `getActivity()` in the `onCreateView` of the `Fragment`

Comment: hey thanks :D let me try this real quick